# Using long ints with Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, int, 16-bit

I am trying to take a number between 100,000 and 10,000, and push each individual number into a queue.

I use a modulus function to do this. However, I am running into issues with the Uno's 16 bit ints, which a cap at 32,767. I have tried using long ints, unsigned ints, and unsigned long ints, but the program still only pushes 0s onto the queue after 32,767. Should I try a char/string approach, or am I missing a solution?

---

```
void fill_que(unsigned int b) {
  int price = b;
  while(price > 0) {
    queue.push(price%10);
    Serial.print(price%10);
    price/=10;
  }
}

int main() {
  unsigned int price1 = 36111;
  fill_que(price1);
}
```

Comment: Unless we see what you have tried it is impossible to provide an answer. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Have you considered using pointers to access the 4-byte memory storage? That way, if you use a memory area that you've defined yourself instead of an integer variable, you might be able to solve your problem... I mean, you can even create your own "integer type"

Comment: @wBB How would I do that?

Comment: You can see the theory on how to use pointers in many videos on the internet. I researched these two now and I think it might help you: 1) Pointers and arrays https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/networking_and_servers/9781787120099/7/ch07lvl1sec43/pointers-and-arrays 2) Programming in c/c++/Arduino https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-HBipu_1P0&list=PL5hh2K9GpFINjqFzOsk2STP9gnaEVfFNO

Comment: @wBB Why use pointers? you will only risk running into undefined behaviour without any gain at all. The long integer type should be sufficient.

Comment: @Johan, you're right about the risks, but from what I understand, on the Arduino it's using, the Integer type LONG isn't working or the Arduino's 16-bit architecture doesn't hold this data length. I don't know if this is the problem because it is not clear in the description, so it could be an option memory management with the size needed to support the data it needs in the list. It seems to me that he has also tried using unsigned LONG

Answer (score 2):

I will make a guess and say, you forgot to change the type of the variable `price`.

It should be:

```cpp
void fill_que(unsigned long b)
{
  unsigned long price = b;
  while(price > 0)
  {
    queue.push(price%10);
    Serial.print(price%10);
    price/=10;
  }
}

int main()
{
  unsigned long price1 = 36111;
  fill_que(price1);
}
```